# Creating a war file of the whole project and a jar file for a class with main method (along with the dependent classes and jar files) using maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, war

I have a CXF WS project from which I need to create a war file of the whole project and a jar file for a class with main method (along with the dependent classes and jar files) (for code re-usability) using maven. Please help me how to do so. I need to know what I need to give in the pom.xml file Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maven way of doing things is that you create one artifact (e.g., *either* a war or a jar) per module. Since you want a jar and a war, you want to utilize at least two modules. Each module goes in its own directory with its own pom.xml file. Presumably, the war would have a dependency on the jar.

Maven has lots of [support](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) for multi-module projects to ease the maintenance and sharing of configuration between the multiple modules.